# How to speed up execution of an SMT solver?

Tags: z3, smt

I find solving non-linear arithmetic expressions even with 16 variables using SMT solvers very time consuming (spanning multiple days). Is there any way to speed up the execution (preferably, while treating the solver as a black box)? 
The only thing that I could think of is specifying the underlying theory (e.g., QF_NIA); are there more?
Also, I am particularly interested in the Z3 SMT solver.